# Jsoup get ID of elements

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom, jsoup

I can not get the ID (or name) of a form using jsoup. For example... the html code is:

```
  <form name="input" action="demo_form_action.asp" method="get">
       Username: <input type="text" name="user">
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

I use the following code to extract the html code of the form, but then how do I get the name?

```
 Elements tds = doc.getElementsByTag("form");
```

thanks!

Comment: Do you have did it yet? I have same problem, Please share your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code illustrates how you can get the id of an element, the element name (= tag) or the attributes of an element. (It is not clear in your question what you want because you talk about getting id or name and your html also contains an attribute 'name')

```
String html = "<form name=\"input\" action=\"demo_form_action.asp\" method=\"get\">\n" +
            "       Username: <input type=\"text\" name=\"user\">\n" +
            "             <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">\n" +
            "  </form>";
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements forms = doc.getElementsByTag("form");
    for (Element form : forms) {
        System.out.println(form.id());
        System.out.println(form.tag());

        Attributes attributes = form.attributes();
        for (Attribute attribute : attributes) {
            System.out.println(attribute.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are assuming that the form has an id, and you know its value. It's not clear if FTSoft has this information.

Comment: I added the id myself because it was easier for me to get to the element like this. I think the problem is not how to get the element, but rather how to get the attribute of an element. That is why I wrote my example code like this.

Comment: FTSoft needs to clarify the problem.

Comment: Indeed, in the mean time I adjusted my code to get the element based on tag name and print id, tag and attributes.

Comment: Yes Antonio, I do not know the value of the id

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var tds =document.getElementsByTagName("form");
console.log(tds[0].getAttribute("name"));
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Km4K/)**

Comment: You are using Javascript and using the org.w3c document's definition.
FTSoft asked about Java, and Jsoup has its own document's definition and methods for DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to consider that in a web page you can find more than one form.

Esecuting the command:

```
Elements tds = doc.getElementsByTag("form");
```

you store inside tds a collection (i.e. an ordered set) of all the Dom's nodes that contain a form.

This collection can be empty, have just an Element, ora have more than one Element.

So it is not clear if you need the name of a specific form , or you want to get the list of all the names of alla forms that are present in the webpage. 
Please clarify.